# It is possible to create batch job as a @Component by using injected JobBuilderFactory to this component

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am curious is it possible to define Spring Batch Job other way then a creating a bean by method. Is any way to define Batch Job by creating a @Component which extend Job and using injected JobBuilderFactory to create a instance to avoid implementing all required method by own hand ?

```
@Component
public class ImportEmployeeJob extends FlowJob {

private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
private final FlowStep printProcessedEmployeeFromCsv;

public ImportEmployeeJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, FlowStep printProcessedEmployeeFromCsv, ApplicationContext context) {
    this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
    this.printProcessedEmployeeFromCsv = printProcessedEmployeeFromCsv;

    jobBuilderFactory.get("importEmployeeJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(new PersonCsvJobExecutionListener())
            .flow(printProcessedEmployeeFromCsv)
            .end()
            .build();
    }

}
```

This is little stupid example but i just want to show you what i mean

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What does your code  look like so far, and what is your problem with it?

Comment: Could your @Morfic look now on the code I send?

Comment: This case dont work and it cant work, but i dont know the way to creating a instance of job by using JobBuilderFactory, for now i came up with an idea to create a job by @PostCostruct and set all necessary object for ImportEmployeeJob by all possible setters method with value of job returned from builder. But i will check it after work. Maybe you have other better idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a factory bean for that. Here is a quick example:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

    @Component
    public static class MyJobFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Job> {

        private final JobBuilderFactory jobs;

        private final StepBuilderFactory steps;

        public MyJobFactoryBean(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
           this.jobs = jobs;
           this.steps = steps;
        }

        @Override
        public Job getObject() {
            Step step = steps.get("step")
                    .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        System.out.println("hello world");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    })
                    .build();

            return jobs.get("job")
                    .start(step)
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            return Job.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSingleton() {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes is work thank you. Is there any workaround to inject bean via custructor or setters instead of field inject ?

Comment: I am asking about constructor injection because in this case spring throw an exception that bean need default costructor. So DI by constructor with injected beans as parametr throw exception. Only injection by setters is possible i think but this is enough to make class easy testable. Sorry but i dont have enough reputation point to vote on answer. Anyway thank you again :)